# The document's format is either unsupported or the document contains binary characters

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, razor, title

I have a cshtml file that was lost before. At that time, I used VS Professional to write the program in that file. After I lost it, I found it again and opened it with the VSD Community tool, but it gave me an error "the document format is not supported or the document contains binary characters".

I tried to convert its format from Bit Character to normal cshtml format but couldn't.

Please help me

This file have troubled like this:

[image: Hex dump]

and i need convert this encode file to this decode file:

[image: Razor sample]

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I see no known format at https://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html that starts with `3E CD`. You seem to have found random or perhaps encrypted data.

Comment: It doesn't seem like you found the actual `.cshtml` that was lost but something else (be it a compiled version, an encrypted version or something else). The first step here would be to identify what you actual got and then maybe there is a way to extract an actual razor view from it.